# Does anyone here have a clue why Solr 9.1 is not starting a backup?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am testing backups on Solr 9.1.0 and I can not get through to make a backup in a local directory successfully.
I setup the directory in solr_in.sh  SOLR_OPTS with -Dsolr.allowPaths=/store/backup but with no success.

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 500,
        "QTime": 17
    },
    "Operation backup caused exception:": "java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /store/backup/mybackup",
    "exception": {
        "msg": "/store/backup/mybackup",
        "rspCode": -1
    },
    "error": {
        "metadata": [
            "error-class",
            "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
            "root-error-class",
            "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"
        ],
        "msg": "/store/backup/mybackup",
        "trace": "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: /store/backup/mybackup\n\tat org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrResponse.getException(SolrResponse.java:61)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.invokeAction(CollectionsHandler.java:348)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleRequestBody(CollectionsHandler.java:297)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.CollectionsAPI$CollectionsCommands.backupCollection(CollectionsAPI.java:94)\n\tat org.apache.solr.api.AnnotatedApi$Cmd.invoke(AnnotatedApi.java:312)\n\tat org.apache.solr.api.AnnotatedApi.call(AnnotatedApi.java:220)\n\tat org.apache.solr.api.V2HttpCall.handleAdmin(V2HttpCall.java:396)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:893)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:584)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.dispatch(SolrDispatchFilter.java:250)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(SolrDispatchFilter.java:218)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.ServletUtils.traceHttpRequestExecution2(ServletUtils.java:257)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.ServletUtils.rateLimitRequest(ServletUtils.java:227)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:213)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:195)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:552)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:600)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1440)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:505)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1355)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.InetAccessHandler.handle(InetAccessHandler.java:177)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:322)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:772)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)\n",
        "code": 500
    }
}
```

The backup request is like:

```
{
    "backup-collection": {
      "name": "mybackup",
      "collection": "collection-test",
      "location": "file:///store/backup"
    }
}
```

Maybe there is something it is not setup properly or missing in my configuration. Please if you have any clue, I'd appreciate any clue. Directory was created and permissions are set for solr process.

thank you

Comment: Does `/store/backup` and `/store/backup/mybackup` exist? Are they writable _for the user that Solr runs under_?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It does!. "mybackup" it suppose to be the name of the backup itself, doesn't it?.

Comment: I gave all the permission on the directory and no way to go through it.

drwxrwxrwx. 4 solr solr 39 Mar 24 15:29 backup

Comment: Verify that selinux isn't triggering as well, depending on which distro you're using; maybe the `solr` user isn't allowed outside of a specific directory (you might see log entries in your syslog, messages or /var/log/audit or similar locations)

Comment: I tested out with Solr 9.2 and unfortunately with the same luck. Directory is perfectly accessible but this operation seems to hit the same stone. No other whatsoever. Running on Centos Stream however I doubt that the OS is the problem.

Comment: I solved the problem. The actual issue was that you have to update the policy file on Solr install etc directory (security.policy). Given read,write and delete permission to the backup directory, it did the magic.